# WPF Custom Control, best way to split string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have got a custom property which will have a name entered into it. As you can see below:

**UserProfile.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Controls
{
    public class UserProfile : Control
    {
        #region Fields
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PhotoSizeProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UserNameProperty;
        #endregion

        static UserProfile()
        {
            // Initialize as lookless control
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UserProfile),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UserProfile)));

            // Initialize dependency properties
            PhotoSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PhotoSize", typeof(Double), typeof(UserProfile), null);
            UserNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserName", typeof(String), typeof(UserProfile), null);
        }

        #region Custom Control Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Size of the user image"), Category("Common Properties")]
        public Double PhotoSize
        {
            get { return (Double)GetValue(PhotoSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PhotoSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Username, split first and last names"), Category("Common Properties")]
        public String UserName
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(UserNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UserNameProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion
    }
    public class CalculateBorder : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Double parm = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
            return new Thickness((double)value / parm);
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public class CalculateFont : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Double parm = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
            return (double)value / parm;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Generic style for my control. There are two TextBlock's, one needs to have the first name and the second should have the second name. What's the best way to split this name given for this without too much over the top code?

**Generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CalculateFont}, 
            ConverterParameter=35, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserProfile}}, 
            Path=(local:UserProfile.PhotoSize)}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
                    <Grid x:Name="circleGrid" Width="{Binding PhotoSize}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="circleBorder"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            CornerRadius="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
                            Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
                            Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
                            BorderBrush="White"
                            BorderThickness="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CalculateBorder}, 
                        ConverterParameter=35, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserProfile}}, 
                        Path=(local:UserProfile.PhotoSize)}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\Users\Martyn Ball\Pictures\11061728_10153409797331063_2946862347621203654_o.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>

                        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="firstName"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding UserName}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="lastName"
                                       FontWeight="Normal"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding UserName}" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Edit:**

Why can't I just create this property like so, `SplitUsername`?

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Username, split first and last names"), Category("Common Properties")]
        public String UserName
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(UserNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UserNameProperty, value); }
        }
        public string[] SplitUsername
        {
            get { return GetValue(UserNameProperty).ToString().Split(' '); }
        }
        #endregion
```

I'm trying to Bind to it in my style, and I get an error saying this it isn't recognized or accessible.

```
Text="{TemplateBinding SplitUsername[0]}"
```

**Edit 2**

Okay, so this is the property which should make an array containing `[0] => "Firstname, [1] => "Secondname"`.

```
public string[] SplitUsername
{
    get { return GetValue(UserNameProperty).ToString().Split(' '); }
}
```

And here is my binding, which isn't working:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="firstName"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            Text="{Binding SplitUsername[0]}" />
<TextBlock Text=" "/>
<TextBlock x:Name="lastName"
            FontWeight="Normal"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            Text="{Binding SplitUsername[1]}" />
```

I don't seem to be getting any errors!

**Edit 3**

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Username, split first and last names"), Category("Common Properties")]
        public String UserName
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(UserNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UserNameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UserNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserName", typeof(String), typeof(UserProfile), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    false,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(UserNamePropertyChanged)));

        private static void UserNamePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            UserProfile profile = sender as UserProfile;

            TextBlock firstName = profile.GetTemplateChild("firstName") as TextBlock;
            TextBlock lastName = profile.GetTemplateChild("lastName") as TextBlock;

            if (firstName != null && lastName != null)
            {
                if (args.NewValue == null)
                {
                    firstName.Text = string.Empty;
                    lastName.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    string newValue = args.NewValue.ToString();

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
                    {
                        firstName.Text = string.Empty;
                        lastName.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] splittedValues = newValue.Split(' ');

                        if (splittedValues.Length == 1)
                        {
                            firstName.Text = newValue;
                            lastName.Text = string.Empty;
                        }
                        else if (splittedValues.Length == 2)
                        {
                            firstName.Text = splittedValues[0];
                            lastName.Text = splittedValues[1];
                        }
                        else if (splittedValues.Length > 2)
                        {
                            firstName.Text = splittedValues[0];
                            lastName.Text = newValue.Substring(splittedValues[0].Length + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: If the text is already in two separate textblocks, i'm not sure what you want to split? But if the full name is just one string, you could split the string at first or last instance of whitespace, depending on how you think of first and last names. This can be done using [.Substring(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) on the string containing the full name.

Comment: @MalteR It will be one string, and I know I can use substring() or something similar, I mean would I make a converter, or a method?

Comment: Why not? :) You could make a 

`string[] GetFirstAndLastNameSeparated(string fullname) {..}` method, not sure about the naming though :)

Comment: I was thinking of using `string[]` but then how would I bind that in my XAML? As I would need to reference `string[0]` for first name and then `string[1]` for second name. @MalteR

Comment: This seems funny. If you can modify the class, I would suggest two properties `FirstName` and `LastName` backed-up by two fields (or auto-properties) and an additional property `FullName` that just concatenate the two previous fields. This seems cleaner to me. Binding will be trivial.

Comment: You can just use `Binding GetFirstAndLastNameSeparated[0]` if you really want to implement it that way.

Comment: See update on post @PatriceGahide

Comment: If the first and last name are already in two separate textblocks, you could just save them individually as Firstname and Lastname, and the make a property called Fullname, that is concatenating the two strings, as Patrice is suggesting.

Comment: @MartynBall You need to make it a DP to use `TemplateBinding`

Comment: @MalteR Just look how the TextBlock's are populated, I enter the name in a property when defining the control, the name should be split and put into the two text blocks, the name isn't hardcoded into the control.

Comment: @PatriceGahide See updated post

Comment: @MartynBall That's just because you coded it that way. From what I understand, nothing prevents you from splitting the name upfront when the control is created, but I may be missing something here.

Comment: @MartynBall `SplitUsername` is still not a DP... You need a DP. I will post an answer later if you can't find your way until then.

Comment: Got it working anyway now. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding from the control template I would suggest you react on the changed UserName property and set the textboxes in code. Like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Username, split first and last names"), Category("Common Properties")]
    public String UserName
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(UserNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserName", typeof(String), typeof(UserProfile), new PropertyMetadata("Firstname Lastname",UserNamePropertyChanged));

    private static void UserNamePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        UserProfile profile = sender as UserProfile;
        profile.RefreshFirstAndLastName();            
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.RefreshFirstAndLastName();
    }

    private void RefreshFirstAndLastName()
    {
        TextBlock firstName = this.GetTemplateChild("firstName") as TextBlock;
        TextBlock lastName = this.GetTemplateChild("lastName") as TextBlock;

        if (firstName != null && lastName != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.UserName))
            {
                firstName.Text = string.Empty;
                lastName.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                string[] splittedValues = this.UserName.Split(' ');

                if (splittedValues.Length == 1)
                {
                    firstName.Text = this.UserName;
                    lastName.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                else if (splittedValues.Length == 2)
                {
                    firstName.Text = splittedValues[0];
                    lastName.Text = splittedValues[1];
                }
                else if (splittedValues.Length > 2)
                {
                    firstName.Text = splittedValues[0];
                    lastName.Text = this.UserName.Substring(splittedValues[0].Length + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know this looks odd when working with WPF. But keep in mind you are **within a control**. You are inside a view and this doesn´t violate MVVM.

**Update 1:**

I found the issue with your code. Change the definition of the UserProfile in MainWindow.xaml like this:

```
<Controls:UserProfile PhotoSize="150" UserName="{Binding Text, ElementName=Username}" />
```

You have to bind to the Text property of the TextBox.

Comment: Thats a much better way! Thanks! Trying to follow MVVM was my main concern.

Comment: Jep, was a long way for me too, understanding that this approach isn´t some dirty workaround.

Comment: Having an issue implementing this, I have added the changed event to my DependencyProperty like so: `UserNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserName", typeof(String), typeof(UserProfile), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    false,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(UserNamePropertyChanged)));`. But for some reason i'm getting an error: `The type initializer for 'Controls.UserProfile' threw an exception.`

Comment: That error is being flagged up on my MainWindow where is test the control: `<Controls:UserProfile PhotoSize="150" UserName="{Binding ElementName=Username}" />`

Comment: Just removed all the code from your method, and it still occurs, is it my DependencyProperty setup ?

Comment: Probably, you made it in the static constructor, didn´t you? Try it exactly as I did - within one line of code without constructor.

Comment: See updated OP (Edit 3), same error using that code.

Comment: According to your update: change `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    false,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(UserNamePropertyChanged)));` to `new PropertyMetadata(
                    "Firstname Lastname",
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(UserNamePropertyChanged)));`

Comment: Seems to have fixed the error, however when changing the property the textblocks are not being updated.

Comment: https://dvtzqq.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y3mSV2k4eYa7KOmNWHNo47NuSWZsP1PW3ZUBJOsZMmrz6SQyLRxrzjSMYQHYNBTbf4dswbfBCWmp17pWqeTKPmGBIwKDvaNxSOHbTjcPnLc-xgJ_2SHFyM5L9ocMBHCzhYvsjZHqJWRbu7qIhl007u5q2RbrG5wCXjml4uHUx1MSAwH4C6LjFu37ZPTInc4p20S/2015-11-26.png?psid=1

Comment: Well your screenshot looks quite okay and the control should work as expected. Indeed I build it on myside and it works like a charm. But notice that I updated my answer again. I missed out the fact that the setting of the textblocks needs to be done after the template has been applied.

Comment: Mind taking a look at my code? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOPtyRizrOoN005dDZOMl9FbDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure, give me a minute to have a look.

Comment: Updated my answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Hey and don´t forget to adapt the UserProfile code correctly. Your code wasn´t exactly alike my answer. I´m out for today but I will have a look on this thread tomorrow, if you need further assistence.

Comment: @MartynBall Did the solution work for you? Please let me know if you need further assistence.

Answer (score 1):

Use Control's Tag property. Split the full name using Split() and store resulting array in Tag property.

Eg;

```
<Button x:Name="BtnName" Content="Anjum Khan" />
<TextBlock Background="#FFEECF0A" Text="{Binding Tag[0], ElementName=BtnName}" />
<TextBlock Background="#FF5DF1AE"  Text="{Binding Tag[1], ElementName=BtnName}"  />


BtnName.Tag = BtnName.Content.ToString().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
```

TextBlocks will show First and Last name respectively. You can build upon this concept.

Your templatebindings will work too :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="firstName"
           FontWeight="Bold"
           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
           Text="{TemplateBinding Tag[0]}" />
```

Comment: Well this is would work, but keep in mind that someone using your custom control could use the Tag property for another intent. This could lead to unexpected misbehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working, this is the binding in **Generic.xaml**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="firstName"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            Text="{Binding SplitUsername[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
<TextBlock Text=" "/>
<TextBlock x:Name="lastName"
            FontWeight="Normal"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            Text="{Binding SplitUsername[1], RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

This is the code behind in **UserProfile.cs**

```
#region Custom Control Properties
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
/// </summary>
[Description("Size of the user image"), Category("Common Properties")]
public Double PhotoSize
{
    get { return (Double)GetValue(PhotoSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PhotoSizeProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
/// </summary>
[Description("Username, split first and last names"), Category("Common Properties")]
public String UserName
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(UserNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UserNameProperty, value); }
}
public string[] SplitUsername
{
    get { return GetValue(UserNameProperty).ToString().Split(' '); }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Not the cleanest thing I have ever seen, but nice workaround!

Comment: Well I suppose this will not behave as expected when you change the value of 'UserName' after the control has been loaded. The splitted values do not update, do they?

Comment: @christoph good point, getting an error `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on this line: `return GetValue(UserNameProperty).ToString().Split(' '); }`

Comment: I prepare another approach to solve your issue. Answer follows within a few minutes.